# Confused first/only time github user - do I need local copy/ies to conduct the following (msg body details)

Tags: github, push, branch, commit, pull-request

I am not a programmer/software/dev to need to get too many git[hub] tools installed, or use anything locally, if someone could please answer for me a very simple question.

Background: the only way I could ask for some modifications for an environment I need to work on, non-software-dev related, is via what it is being described to me as a request I need to produce as described below:

- go to this GitHub URL (I have a login for that)
- create a branch
- modify files X, Y and Z (apparently some orchestration configs) you need, as described in other instructions
- commit
- push
- create a PR, and someone will check, approve and trigger the orchestration tool with the configs you modified, and get you what you need

Is all of the above possible using the web interface to GitHub, via my browser, without the [almost all instructions I found, so far, online, pointing to] installation of git (desktop or CLI) on my laptop, creation of a local copy of the main/master repository, then branching locally, then ... ?!?

Comment: Yes, it should be possible to do everything in the web browser.

Comment: Can't find a branch option, though, in the browser. The only way I found able to change something is going into one of the files I need to modify, in the master, "edit" it, which prompts me to create a fork under my account, then a branch within. Forks are frowned upon here, so it doesn't look like I have a choice other than installing git locally, and pulling all down, to create a branch directly relatable, then PR it ... if I correctly understand the process

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do all of those things you listed out via the browser as long as you follow the steps correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the file in the browser you can click edit and edit the file. After you are done editing, you can type a commit message and create a pull request on a new branch.
[image: Form at the bottom of the page]

Here you can click on create a new branch and start a pull request. It will do those things automatically.
If you have no write access of the repository it will actually directly create a fork on your account with the changes and start a pull request...

[image]

[image]